# How to divide nested routes in Roda

Tags: ruby, roda

I write an application using Roda.
I have a nested router like this:

```
   route 'chats' do |r|
      env['warden'].authenticate!
      r.is do
        @current_user = env['warden'].user

        r.get do
          # code is here
        end

        r.post do
          # code is here
        end
      end

      r.on :String do |chat_id|
        r.is 'messages' do
          # code is here

          r.get do
            # code is here
          end

          r.post do
            # code is here
          end
        end
      end
    end
```

I want to divide one big code-block into two routes like this:

```
route 'chats' do |r|
  # code is here
end
route 'chats/:chat_id/messages' do |r, chat_id|
  # code is here
end
```

Please, help. How to do it right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to enable 2 plugins:

- [multi_route](http://roda.jeremyevans.net/rdoc/classes/Roda/RodaPlugins/MultiRoute.html) - to allow splitting routes between separate files,
- [shared_vars](http://roda.jeremyevans.net/rdoc/classes/Roda/RodaPlugins/SharedVars.html) - to pass variables down the routes.

Then, on the highest level declare routes as follows:

```
  # routes/root.rb
  class YourApp::Web
    route do |r|
      r.on('chats') do
        r.is do
          r.route 'chats'
        end

        r.is(String, 'messages') do |chat_id|
          shared[:chat_id] = chat_id
          r.route 'chats_messages'
        end
      end
    end
  end
```

After that you can put *chats* and *chats_messages* into separate files:

```
  # routes/chats.rb
  class YourApp::Web
    route ('chats') do |r|
      r.get do
        # ....
      end

      r.post do
        # ....
      end
    end
  end

  # routes/chats_messages.rb
  class YourApp::Web
    route ('chats_messages') do |r|
      chat_id = shared[:chat_id]
      r.get do  
        # ....
      end

      r.post do  
        # ....
      end
    end
  end
```

Maybe there is also other solution. I've shared what worked for me. Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you! I will try it